# spark 1.6 - RDD creation and history

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark 1.6 with Python and I would like to keep track of the  list of previous sessions and the history .

For example : RDD created 2 days back with persist option .
created RDD  and it was active for the current session only and when I exit the session I dont see the track of the previous transformations .

Any settings or parameter to be configured ?

Thanks 
Vijay

Comment: What do you mean sessions ? SparkSession ?

Comment: yes , the spark session that gets started when we hit -pyspark command

Comment: The session only live in runtime. So I guest you want to see history log  form Spark UI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use :history command in your spark REPL.
It will provide all the commands used for current session.

```
scala> :history
  1  exit
  2  quit
  3  quit;
  4  close();
  5  val rdd = sc.textFile(“README.md”)
  6  val rdd = sc.textFile("README.md")
  7  rdd.count();
  8  val rdd = sc.textFile("README.md")
  9  rdd.count()
 10  val rdd = sc.textFile("/Users/**/bashrc.txt")
 11  rdd.count()
 12  val rdd = sc.textFile("README.md")
 13  rdd.count();
 14  val rdd = sc.textFile("README.md")
 15  rdd.count()
 16  quit
 17  exit
 18  exit;
 19  history
 20  :history


 scala>
```